# cmake --target source directory does not exist

Tags: c++, cmake, setuptools

I am compiling a rather big C++ project with cmake.
The project has several targets defined in the CMakeLists.txt of the various subdirectories

I can create a folder somewhere and use cmake to prepare compilation of the targets, and compile any of the target :

> cmake ..
> make -j8 cytosim

And this works.
However, if I call cmake with a target :

> cmake .. --target cytosim

I get the error

> CMake Error: The source directory ".../build/cytosim" does not exist.

I thought target was supposed to be a module/library/executable target... What am I missing ?

Comment: I think you need 2 commands `cmake .. && cmake --build  . --target cytosim`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMake `--target` argument is usable in CMake Build Mode ([`--build`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project)).

Try `cmake --build .. --target cytosim`

Comment: Thanks; as pointed above : cmake .. && cmake --build  . --target cytosim